# jvm memory capacities changing frequently

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I have two tomcat servers running the same web app that exhibit very different behavior regarding JVM memory capacity. The main difference between the two servers is that server 1 has 15gb of memory while server 2 has 3.75gb (this difference was apparently left over from a problem that was addressed, but the server size was not scaled back).

On server 1 we have:

```
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=245500672 -XX:MaxHeapSize=3928010752 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

On server 2:

```
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=61513536 -XX:MaxHeapSize=984216576 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedOops
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

Server 2 exhibits the typical behavior I'm used to seeing regarding capacity vs utilization. The capacity (survivor in this case) stays somewhat stable while utilization changes dynamically:

[image]

However server 1 shows large & frequent changes to capacity:

[image]

Eden space shows a similar pattern. Old space is reasonably tame on server 1 as expected, but still changes significantly more frequently than server 2.

Charts are from publishing "jstat -gc" values. Survivor spaces shown are S0C + S1C. Is this a factor of UseParallelGC? I wouldn't think so, but I can't see much other difference between the servers. Server 1 does get a somewhat higher transaction volume, but I doubt it explains this.

Comment: jstat merely samples, you should use GC logging to get an accurate picture of GC events. You can use gcviewer to visualize logs.

Comment: This should not be due to UseParallelGC, because this is the default for Java 7.